# Curly Braces in python Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

Running subprocess won't handle curly braces correctly

```
# Python 2.7.4

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('ls src/*.cpp',shell=True): 
src/tonemap.cpp src/pch.cpp

subprocess.Popen('ls src/{t,p}*.cpp', shell=True)
ls: cannot access src/{p,t}*.cpp: No such file or directory
```

The same program will work on a different machine with python 2.7.2. Both systems use bash shells.

Do you the reason and how can I fix it?

EDIT:

Invoking the command directly from the command line returns the correct result:

```
ls src/{t,p}*.cpp
src/tonamep.cpp src/pch.cpp
```

Comment: And how can I roll back from 2.7.4 to 2.7.2 on a Linux Mint?

Comment: Your second example works for me...what shell is on both systems?

Comment: @TomFenech They are both bash shells

Comment: and what happens in the shell when you run `ls src/{t,p}*.cpp` on the "broken" system, does it work?

Comment: Yes it works, output is 'tonemap.cpp pch.cpp' as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`shell=True` runs `/bin/sh` that doesn't support this syntax. Specify `bash` explicitly:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call('ls src/{t,p}*.cpp', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Comment: Does `/bin/sh` on some systems run `bash` then?

Comment: @TomFenech: On my system it runs `dash`. `/bin/sh` is usually "posix"ly. Even if it runs `bash`; it probably runs it in a posix mode. I don't know whether a posix shell should support brace expansion.

Comment: To confirm, the POSIX shell does *not* support brace expansion.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Popen executed correctly, error is reported from `ls`.
It should give same error when you execute the command:

```
ls src/{t,p}*.cpp
```

in terminal.

Comment: Right, but the command invoked by the shell is not 'ls src/{t,p}*.cpp'

Comment: it has issued the right command. Why do you say it has not invoked your command?

Comment: Because the output is not 'tonemap.cpp pch.cpp'

Comment: What happens when you execute ls src/{t,p}*.cpp in your command line/terminal?

Comment: It works, output is 'tonemap.cpp pch.cpp' as expected

Comment: Can you find which ls being used? by issuing 'which ls' from Popen and from your terminal?

Comment: 'which ls' returned /bin/ls

Comment: Thanks. It shows where is the problem. ls from bin does not handle this syntax (i have verified in Mac). I think you can follow J.F. Sebastian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other machine uses a different shell that doesn't handle that syntax.