# python: calling shell command with subprocess

Tags: bash, shell, python-2.7, subprocess, mencoder

I am calling `mencoder` from a `python` (2.7.3) function with `subprocess.call` (I am using `ipython`), but it doesn't work, whereas when I copy and paste the command on the terminal shell it does. I think I am making some stupid mistake with strings. I am very confused because I am running this `python` function on two distinct computing clusters, with same `python` version, but different version of `mencoder`, and this command works on one cluster but not on the other.

this is the `python` script

```
base = r'/home/afylot/pics/'
var = r'b2component'
os.chdir(base)
listdir = [x[0] for x in os.walk('.')][1:-1]
listdir.reverse()
dirs = ','.join(listdir)
dirs2=dirs.replace(r"./z",r"")
def cmd2(x): return r"mencoder mf://z{"+dirs2+"}/"+x+r".png -mf fps=1 -ovc lavc -o "+x+r"_mpeg4.avi"
def cmd3(x): return r"mencoder -speed 1/4 "+x+r"_mpeg4.avi -ovc copy -nosound -o "+x+r"_smpeg4.avi"
res2=subprocess.call([cmd2(var)],shell=True)
res3=subprocess.call([cmd3(var)],shell=True)
```

and this is the error message:

```
MEncoder SVN-r37381-4.6 (C) 2000-2015 MPlayer Team
success: format: 16  data: 0x0 - 0x0
MF file format detected.
[mf] filelist: z{5.056,4.996,4.936,4.877,4.819,4.762,4.705,4.648,4.592,4.537,4.482,4.428,4.374,4.321,4.268,4.216,4.164,4.113,4.063,4.012,3.963,3.914,3.865,3.817,3.769,3.722,3.675,3.629,3.583,3.538,3.493,3.448,3.404,3.361,3.317,3.275,3.232,3.190,3.149,3.108,3.067,3.027,2.987,2.909,2.870,2.832,2.794,2.756,2.719,2.682,2.646,2.609,2.574,2.538,2.503,2.469,2.434,2.400,2.367,2.333,2.300,2.268,2.235,2.203,2.171,2.140,2.109,2.078,2.048}/b2component.png
[mf] number of files: 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
MEncoder SVN-r37381-4.6 (C) 2000-2015 MPlayer Team
File not found: 'b2component_mpeg4.avi'
Failed to open b2component_mpeg4.avi.
Cannot open file/device.

Exiting...
```

On the other cluster the command from within the `python` function works. If, on the same cluster, I try to launch the command from terminal, it also works

```
mencoder mf://z{5.056,4.996,4.936,4.877,4.819,4.762,4.705,4.648,4.592,4.537,4.482,4.428,4.374,4.321,4.268,4.216,4.164,4.113,4.063,4.012,3.963,3.914,3.865,3.817,3.769,3.722,3.675,3.629,3.583,3.538,3.493,3.448,3.404,3.361,3.317,3.275,3.232,3.190,3.149,3.108,3.067,3.027,2.987,2.909,2.870,2.832,2.794,2.756,2.719,2.682,2.646,2.609,2.574,2.538,2.503,2.469,2.434,2.400,2.367,2.333,2.300,2.268,2.235,2.203,2.171,2.140,2.109,2.078,2.048}/b2component.png -mf fps=1 -ovc lavc -o b2component_mpeg4.avi
```

On cluster A, where the `python` function fails, I have `bash` 4.2.25.
On cluster B, where the `python` function works, I am running `tcsh` 6.17.00

---

I have tested the same command with wildcards (like `*` and `?`) and it works from within the python function. The problem is with the braces `{}`. The funny thing is that on cluster B, that is running `tcsh`, the wildcards do not work, but the braces do work!

Can anybody suggest how to overcome this limitation with braces? because I want to control the order of dirs2 from within the python function, so using the `*` will not do what I want.

Comment: Does the `/home/afylot/pics/` directory exist on both hosts?

Comment: yes, also because, as you can see from the error message, dirs2 is built correctly

Comment: Ah, true. Check the permissions on that directory on the failing host?

Comment: but the direct shell command works, I mean if I cut and paste on the terminal, it just works fine. It must be a problem with python strings

Comment: On the host where the script fails you can run that same command manually?

Comment: yes, I can, the command is at the bottom of my question

Comment: I've been focusing on the wrong issue. The problem is that the first command is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the same as in [Curly Braces in python Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659579/curly-braces-in-python-popen)
, and the solution is to use

```
subprocess.call(cmd2(v), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

because otherwise `shell=True` runs `/bin/sh`

Comment: I would avoid `shell=True` and pass the arguments as a list instead: `call(["mencoder"] + ["mf://{path}/{x}{r}.png".format(**vars()) for path in listdir] + ["-mf", "fps=1", "-ovc", "lavc", "-o", x+r+"_mpeg4.avi"])`