# Python shell call to exiftool

Tags: python, shell, exiftool

I have an image, 1.tiff, from which I want to copy the exif data to two other images, 2.tiff and 3.tiff.
from the normal shell I can write the same exif data to multiple images by typing

```
exiftool -m -overwrite_original -TagsFromFile "1.tiff" {"2.tiff","3.tiff"}
```

For some reason, I am not able to do this from python.
If I execute the same shell command from a python script, i.e.

```
os.system('exiftool -m -overwrite_original -TagsFromFile "1.tiff" {"2.tiff","3.tiff"}')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: File not found - {2.tiff,3.tiff}
```

It works, however, if I call the command for every single image, to be written to. i.e.

```
os.system('exiftool -m -overwrite_original -TagsFromFile "1.tiff" "2.tiff"')
os.system('exiftool -m -overwrite_original -TagsFromFile "1.tiff" "3.tiff"')
```

But, as I am going to call the command several thousand times, reading the exif data from 1.tiff over and over again is simply too slow.
Do you have any suggesting on how to copy exif data from one source image to multiple images while only reading the source image once?

The following zip-file contain a working bash-script and the non-working python equivalent: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm8fdkdfq7hqi8m/folder.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 2):

If your only purpose is to use exiftool in python then why not use [this module](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/)? Sorry I do not have enough reputation to post comments yet. For example:

```
 import exiftool

 files = ["a.jpg", "b.png", "c.tif"]
 with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
         metadata = et.get_metadata_batch(files)
```

UPDATE: Sorry I stand corrected. that module does not perform exif modification.

Comment: As far as I know, that module is only for reading exif data, not writing.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/piexif, perhaps this is what you are looking for, it provides reading and writing.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` tends to act up like that, especially on Windows. You'll probably have more success with [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
subprocess.call(['exiftool','-m','-overwrite_original','-TagsFromFile','1.tiff','{"2.tiff","3.tiff"}'])
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the same when using subprocess.call

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659579/curly-braces-in-python-popen) question and Rawing answer, the problem seems to be that /bin/sh that doesn't support this curly braces. The solution therefore is to set executable='/bin/bash' in subprocess.Popen

```
subprocess.Popen(['exiftool','-m','-overwrite_original','-TagsFromFile','1.tiff','{"2.tiff","3.tiff"}'],executable='/bin/bash')
```